# How to add admin bar only page?

Tags: admin-menu, admin-bar, add-menu-page, settings-api

I successfully managed to create admin bar item using this:

```
add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'toolbar_link_to_mypage', 999);
function toolbar_link_to_mypage($wp_admin_bar){
    global $wp_admin_bar;

    $theme_menu = array(
        'id' => 'theme_page',
        'title' => __('test', 'test'),
        'href' => 'http://mysite.com/my-page/',
        'meta' => array('class' => 'test')
    );

    $wp_admin_bar->add_node($theme_menu);
}
```

But I can't figure out what is the correct way to create an admin panel **OPTIONS PAGE (not sub-menu item! Two answers are about sub-menus already)** for `'href' => '',` parameter. I can't simply use `add_menu_page();` because that would attach it to left navigation as well. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a new array for the new item and pass the `parent` parameter as the id of this already created item. 
In your case, the args array should be like this:

```
$args = array(
    'id' => 'my-item',
    'title' => 'My Item',
    'href' => '#',
    'parent' => 'theme_page',
    'meta' => array(
        'title' => __('Click Me'),
    ),
);
```

[This post](http://blog.rutwick.com/add-items-anywhere-to-the-wp-3-3-admin-bar) has a complete explanation of how and where you can add items to the admin bar and the usage of the `parent` parameter.

Comment: I didn't make myself clear enough. I know how to create sub-pages, too but I'm wondering how to create OPTIONS PAGE for admin bar item :)

Comment: Options page? You mean you want to be able to add new menu items from an options page?

Comment: I can use `add_menu_page();` to register new options page in left sidebar in admin panel. But I can't do that in top admin bar - I can only specify link. I'm looking for a way to create options page for each link in that bar.

Comment: You add the page via the regular way, using `add_menu_page`, and then follow this: http://justintadlock.com/archives/2011/06/13/removing-menu-pages-from-the-wordpress-admin tutorial to remove that page from the sidebar menu. Then, for the href part of your admin bar item, pass the url for the removed settings page.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that will work :

```
 add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'toolbar_link_to_mypage', 999);
function toolbar_link_to_mypage($wp_admin_bar){
    global $wp_admin_bar;

    $wp_admin_bar->add_menu(array(
        'id' => 'theme_page',
        'title' => __('test', 'test'),
        'href' => 'http://mysite.com/my-page/',
        'meta' => array('class' => 'test')
    ));

   $wp_admin_bar->add_menu(array(
        'id' => 'theme_page_child',
        'title' => __('Child test', 'child-test'),
        'href' => 'http://mysite.com/my-page/',
        'meta' => array('class' => 'child-test'),
    'parent' => 'theme_page'
    ));

}
```

In the first `add_menu` I have added a parent link
In the next `add_menu` I am using another attribute 'parent' which is referring to the id of 'parent' here the 'parent' is 'theme_page' we created above.

Comment: Yes, but I'm wondering how to create OPTIONS PAGE for admin bar item. I know how to create sub-menu item. Any ideas?